# Make a large table in html

Tags: html

I have an assignment were in one part I have to make a 10x6 table. Know I know how to make a basic table using:

```html
<table border=1 width=80%>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I just wanted to know if there is any way to get  a large table like a 10x6 without having to type out 10 tr sections and 6 td sections in each.

Comment: Copy + Paste...

Comment: Copy and paste perhaps

Comment: It's also interesting to see such simple example code being written wrong. (Don't use `border` and `width` directly on the element, and alwasy  encase values in double quotes `"80%"`).
Also, a `<table>` should always have a `<thead>` and `<tbody>`... I could go on.

Comment: Sorry if some stuff is wrong. This class isn't even meant for html, my professor just decided to slide it into the lesson plan for like a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In only HTML, no. Copy and Paste as mentioned before.
But PHP would allow you to do that.
(Also, remember not to use tables for formatting )

Answer (score 0):

You can use an online table generator to auto generate the laborious code for you.  A quick google search will return many options.

Answer (score 0):

An example using php script

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Doc: stacktestphp.php</title>
</head>

<table border=1 width=80%>
    <!-- you can add table headers -->
    <?php
    $rowNr=10;
    $colNr=6;
        for($i=0;$i<$rowNr;$i++){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <?php
                for($j=0;$j<$colNr;$j++){
                ?>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $i.",".$j; ?>
                </td>
                <?php
                }
            ?>      
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```